# Adding field to existing feature class using ArcObjects and Java?

Tags: arcobjects

I tried to add a new field to an existing feature class using ArcObjects and Java. This is the code:

```
IFeatureClass FcTes=sdeConnexion.connectionSDE().openFeatureClass("name of feature class");
    IField testField=new Field();
    IFieldEdit testField2=(IFieldEdit2)testField;
    testField2.setName("symbol1");
    testField2.setAliasName("symbol1");
    FeatureClass FC=new FeatureClass(FcTes);
    ISchemaLock schemaLock = (ISchemaLock)FC;
    try{
    schemaLock.changeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriExclusiveSchemaLock);

    FcTes.addField(testField2);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        schemaLock.changeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriSharedSchemaLock);
    }
```

when I executed it, this exception fired:

> AutomationException: 0x80040220 - The application is not licensed to
>   create or modify schema for this type of data  in 'Esri GeoDatabase'
>     at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjRef.nativeVtblInvokeNative(Native
>   Method)   at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjRef.a(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjRef.a(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.esri.arcgis.interop.Dispatch.vtblInvoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.esri.arcgis.geodatabase.IClassProxy.addField(Unknown Source)  at
>   travaux.ConnectGeoDB2.main(ConnectGeoDB2.java:58)

Can anyone see what I did wrong?

I have ArcGIS 10.2 Advanced (Server and Desktop) and in my project I'm working with arcobject.jar of ArcGIS Server.

Comment: Please edit the question to contain the version of ArcGIS and license level.

Comment: I'have arcgis 10.2 advanced(server and desktop) and in my project i'm working with arcobject.jar of arcgis server

Comment: Please **edit the question** to contain critical details. It's not fair to those who would answer your question to need to mine the comments for this information.

Comment: As the answer below indicates, you must tell ArcObjects about you license(s).

Answer (score 1):

Even if your ArcGIS license supports this particular feature (let's say you have an advanced license) you still need to specify the license level in your ArcEngine code. For example:

```
RuntimeManager.BindLicense(ProductCode.EngineOrDesktop, LicenseLevel.GeodatabaseUpdate);
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like a licence issue.
Please have a look at the following link:
http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISengine/java/doc/06e45adf-ad58-4c3b-8f79-4300a1ce045d.htm